# Change Between GNU Make and Clearmake Compilers During a Build

Tags: makefile, gnu, clearcase, clearmake

Is it possible to switch from Clearmake to GNU make at a certain point in a build and then switch back? If so, how so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, neither GNU make nor clearmake are compilers.

All make versions are just tools for running other commands, so you can just write a rule that will run a different make as a command:

```
run-make:
        gmake do-something
```

Now when the `run-make` rule is invoked it will call GNU make (here called `gmake`, but it might be called `make` or whatever) to build a target `do-something`.  Once that's done it'll return back to the current make version (presumably clearmake).

With the minimal information you provided, that's the best we can do.